# How to change microphone for recording when handsfree is connected in Samsung devices?

Tags: android, audio, samsung-mobile, opensl, jack

I'm working with `OpenSL_ES` in Android, and having some issues with the mic source selection in Samsung devices when I connect earphones with handsfree.

The problem is that no matter what mic source I set in `OpenSL_ES`, the gain configuration changes but the mic is always the handsfree mic. In other words, I cannot use the device built-in mic when I connect a handsfree device.

I have tried:

Changing the mic source to all available sources:

```
//ioInternals.micSource = SL_ANDROID_RECORDING_PRESET_NONE;       
//ioInternals.micSource = SL_ANDROID_RECORDING_PRESET_GENERIC;    
ioInternals.micSource = SL_ANDROID_RECORDING_PRESET_CAMCORDER;
//ioInternals.micSource = SL_ANDROID_RECORDING_PRESET_VOICE_RECOGNITION;
//ioInternals.micSource = SL_ANDROID_RECORDING_PRESET_VOICE_COMMUNICATION;
//ioInternals.micSource = SL_ANDROID_RECORDING_PRESET_UNPROCESSED;

res = (*recorderConfig)->SetConfiguration(recorderConfig, SL_ANDROID_KEY_RECORDING_PRESET,&ioInternals.micSource, sizeof(SLuint32));
```

**None of the above allows me to change source (only gain configuration)**

Some where I've read that a "hack" could be set to `SL_ANDROID_RECORDING_PRESET_NONE` in `OpenSL_ES` and then use MediaRecorder class in Java to prepare a recorder while changing the mic sources (which are like 9) to check if one of them would make the phone change the source to the device built-in mic and so `OpenSL_ES` would take the default mic at the moment. This doesn't make too much sense as they are working in different contexts, but took the time to make a test, and MediaRecorder does not change the mic source when handsfree is connected neither.

An option I see is to develop my mic module in Jack library from Samsung assuming that library can change the mic source. However I'm not certain that it is possible.

**Question:**
Do you know how I can resolve this issue?

I have seen a few apps that manage to make this work, but I have no idea what they are doing to accomplish the task.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Didn't not solve the issue with OpenSL_ES directly, it depends on the ROM, using Samsung's Jack is the only way I've found, did not have the opportunity to check how this is working in devices with Android 9+